Linkedin API retrieve organization's logo
Retrieve a link to the organization's logo through API. I am trying to get an organization logo using API 202409 according to the documentation:
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationsLookup?projection=(results({Orgaization_ID}(logoV2(original~:playableStreams,cropped~:playableStreams,cropInfo))))&ids=List({Orgaization_ID})' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}' \
-H 'Linkedin-Version: 202409'

Using this API point, I get the error “projection parameter is not allowed for this endpoint”:

The value formats are digitalmediaAsset URNs. For example, urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:123ABC. These URNs need to be decorated in order to return image URLs. Include ~:playableStreams in the projection parameter to request the image URLs.

Why do I get this error if the documentation clearly states that the “projection” parameter is supported? How can I get a link to my organization's logo?

TL;DR
Change /rest to /v2.
Long answer
According to the official LinkedIn changelog:

Starting with version 202307, API decoration will no longer be supported for any API. We’ve created this video to assist you with this change.

Unfortunately, as of now, LinkedIn has not provided an alternative method to achieve this without using decorations. I'm still using v2 to all of my calls.
